# Possible to install PyPy on Cygwin using Cygwin Ports?

Tags: cygwin, pypy

I found the page https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/pypy/ci/master/tree/pypy-1.9-1.cygport, which led me to believe that it'd be possible to install `pypy` on `cygwin` using https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/.

However, `pypy` was not found as an option when I did:

```
$ cygstart -- setup-x86.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
```

### 1. Is it possible to install pypy on cygwin via Cygwin Ports?

### 2. If yes to {1}: are there online instructions on how to do {1}?

### 3. Can you give me a URL to {2}?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it's possible, it's inefficient: last PyPy version is 5.4.1, and you're talking about 1.91

Comment: In that case, is it possible to install `PyPy` _any other way_ on Cygwin?

Answer (score -1):

All the instructions for installing from cygports are here:
https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/

However as you can see from
ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports/x86/setup.ini
ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports/x86_64/setup.ini

the `pypy` package is not anymore available.

You can ask details to the project owner on
the `cygwin-ports-general` mailing list
https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/mailman/

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: @FrankerZ I assume the expanded answer meet your "standards".

Comment: They are not "my" standards; they are the site's standards. (I'm also not the one who downvoted you). Providing link-only answers cause issues for future visitors if the sites go offline (Which is why we prefer that most of the content is copied here.)